# passing cursor to a function does not work always

Tags: oracle, plsql, parallel-processing, cursor

I have the below procedure and the functions, I pass the cursor result as an argument to the function load_in_parallel. The issue is that sometimes the entries are processed and other time it doesn't. I really don't understand why it happens. Could it be due to the size of the result? Please see the PL/SQL procedure and function as below,

```
    procedure COPY_REPORT_CONTENTS is
  begin
    begin

  -- START PARALLEL processing from here
  for rec in (
        select /*+ parallel(5) */ * from table(load_in_parallel(CURSOR(
            select gen_report_id, creation_ts, selection_criteria, content from stage_table stgrep where not exists(select 1 from content rep where rep.report_id = stgrep.gen_report_id) and nvl(stgrep.gen_report_id, 0) <> 0)))
           )
    LOOP
          --some processing here
    END LOOP;
    exception
      when others then
         ROLLBACK;
         raise;
    end;
  end;

  function load_in_parallel (c_pis_a1 IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
  return vdps_load_stats
  PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION c_pis_a1 BY ANY)
  PIPELINED
  IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  begin
    loop
      begin
        fetch c_pis_a1 into r_pis_a1;
        exit when c_pis_a1%notfound;
        --some processing
     commit;
     exception
    when others then
        rollback;
        --move the records to failed table and continue with next records
        commit;
    end;
    end loop;
    close c_pis_a1;
  PIPE ROW(v_vdps_load_stats);
  RETURN;
     end;
```

Any help will really be appreciated.

Note: included the missing exception block.